# How to synchronize data within programs using a database?

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a very small program that is going to be used by two or more computers at the same time. It's a small program that can add string to the list and remove it from the list. I save all these strings in a remote postgres database. When I delete string from the list, it gets deleted from the database however if the program is running on other computer you still can see this string. Currently I have only one option in mind which is refreshing data in program every x time ? Are there better options ? Database is very small, only one column and shouldnt be more than 100 rows.

Comment: Look at pubsub systems like Redis or RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never allow client programs to interact with a remote database directly. Exposing your database to the clients is a huge security problem. You should always have a server-program in between which communicates with the clients, validates their input, communicate with the database, and then tells the clients what they want to know.

This would also give you the ability to add push-updates to your network protocol (when one client makes a change, update the database and also inform the other client about the change).

But when you really want to take the risk and you consider a server-program too much complexity, you could add a timestamp to every row when it gets changed. That way you could refresh the clients at regular intervals by querying only for the rows which got changed since the last refresh.

Another option would be to allow the clients to communicate with each other in a peer-to-peer manner. When a client makes a change, it doesn't just notify the database, it also notifies the other clients via separate network connections. In order to do that, the clients need to know each others IP addresses or at least each others hostnames. When these aren't known, you could have the clients write their IPs to another table of the database when they connect, so the other client can query for it. Just make sure the entries get deleted, so you don't annoy every single IP address some client ever had.